# Read an input file to an array

Tags: c

How can I read a text file's content and put it into an array? For example, I have 3, 2, 1, 0 in my text file and I want to read the file and store the values in an array. I am using the `fscanf` function to do this:

```
int a[4];
point = fopen("test.txt", "r");

for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    fscanf( point , "%d " , &a[i]);              
}

// printing put the values ,but i dont get the text file values

for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    printf("%d\n" , a[i]);  
}
```

I ran this program but I didn't get the values present in the text file. Can anybody please suggest a way to do this? I want to specifically solve it with the `fscan` function.

Comment: What did you get? Did your file contain a space after each value? You should also add checking that `fopen()` and `fscanf()` worked.

Comment: [tag:c++]? or [tag:c]? This looks like the latter. The former tag should probably be removed.

Comment: Add your file content  and your out put in question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Load numbers from text file in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1658530/load-numbers-from-text-file-in-c)

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1658530/load-numbers-from-text-file-in-c/18822514#18822514

Answer (score 1):

you can find your answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1658530/load-numbers-from-text-file-in-c):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    FILE* f = fopen("test.txt", "r");
    int n = 0, i = 0;
    int numbers[5]; // assuming there are only 5 numbers in the file

    while( fscanf(f, "%d,", &n) > 0 ) // parse %d followed by ','
    {
        numbers[i++] = n;
    }

    fclose(f);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`fscanf` if used for reading data from the stream and storing them according to the parameter format into the specified locations. You can get the reference [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf).

So you must check the values' format in the file, for your example, you have "3,2,1,0" in the file, you should set the format to "%d," because each value was followed a ','.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a[4], i;
    FILE *point = fopen("test.txt", "r");

    for(i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        fscanf( point , "%d," , &a[i]);
    }

    // printing put the values ,but i dont get the text file values

    for(i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n" , a[i]);
    }
}
```

I test it with my codeblocks on windows, I get

```
3
2
1
0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main() {
    int a[4];
    FILE* point = fopen("test.txt", "r");

    if (NULL == point) {
        perror("File not found!");
        exit(-1);
    }

    for (int i = 0; fscanf(point, "%d%*c", &a[i]) > 0 && i < 4; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", a[i]);
    }

    fclose(point);
}
```

test.txt:

```
11234, 2234, 32345, 42542
```

Comment: This program just prints the first value in the text file- 3. This doesnt print the other values present in the txt file.Any solution?

Comment: err...how did you run the program? I have a text file here with 4 numbers and this program still prints all 4 numbers

Answer (score 0):

Always make sure what you are reading from the value. If you are reading characters from the file ok. But if you want to read integers always make sure you read them as characters and convert them to integers.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char a;
    FILE *point;
    int i, b[4];
    point = fopen("test.txt", "r");
    for(i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            a = fgetc( point); 
        b[i] = atoi(&a);              
    }
// printing put the values ,but i dont get the text file values
    for(i = 0; i < 4; i++) 
        printf("%d\n" , b[i]);  
}
```

this is my text file,

```
3210
```

this is my output,

```
3
2
1
0
```

Answer (score 0):

First you should know the order in which the numbers are written in the text file, if they are separated by a single space, you can use your code like this:

```
for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
{
fscanf(point, "%d ", &a[i]);
}
```

You should leave a space after `%d`.
If numbers are written in separate lines, you can use your code like this:

```
 for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
{
fscanf(point, "%d\n", &a[i]);
}
```

That's all, you can print those values as your wish.