# Convert entire array of characters into integer in C

Tags: c

I'm reading input from a file and trying to create a numerical value from the strings I take in.

I tried simply using the atoi but that doesn't work on characters.
Then I tried using a forloop over my array of characters but then I got error because some characters are actually integers.
Then I tried using ifstatement to check if the characters themselves are integers and just add it to my "sum" manually.

But so far all I get is errors and errors, I'm not sure where my logic is wrong.

In C an array is simply a pointer right? So to access the value at a certain index I use *arr[num] right?

This is my code

```
    char newlineC;
    char input[14];
    while(fscanf(fp,"%s%c",input, &newlineC)!=EOF){
        int val = 0;
        int x;
        for(x=0; x<14; x++){
            if(isdigit(*input[x])){
                val = val + input[x];           
            }else{
                int p = atoi(input[x]);
                val = val + p;              
            }
        }
```

I've tried the strol function... didn't work either. I've been at this for so long I feel dumb that I am stumped on something that seems so simple. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `isdigit(*input[x])`?? An array is not simply a pointer, in fact it is a whole distinct type.

Comment: `input[x]` is already a `char`, you cannot dereference it, the compiler should have given you an error about this. `atoi(input[x])` is also wrong, because `atoi` expects a pointer to `char`, not a single character. Again the compiler must have warned you about this. Read the compiler warnings.

Comment: Did you see this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1658530/load-numbers-from-text-file-in-c/18822514#18822514

Comment: To be most clear on what you want to do, it is always a good idea to show the input you *have* and the output you'd *expect*. Currently you don't. So I feel it's unclear what you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing the wrong types all over the place.

```
char input[14];
```

this declares an `char` array of dimension 14. `input[i]` is the `i`th `char` in
the array, it has type `char`. It's not a pointer, you cannot dereference it,
that's why `*input[x]` fails. In fact the compiler should have given you an
error there, this error:

```
invalid type argument of unary ‘*’ (have ‘int’)
```

The same problem with `atoi`. It expects a pointer to `char` that points to a
string. `input[x]` is single `char`, you cannot pass to `atoi`. Again the
compiler should have warned you.

```
fscanf(fp,"%s%c",input, &newlineC)
```

This is very clumsy. If the input is larger than 13 characters, you will
overflow the buffer. A better way would be:

```
fscanf(fp, "%13s%c", input, &newline);
```

Or even better

```
int val;
fscanf(fp, "%d", &val);
```

Another error: if you know that `input[x]` is a digit, then the integer that the
digit represent is `input[x] - '0'`. So this should be the calculation:

```
val = val + input[x] - '0';
```

Overall I would use `fgets` and `strtol`:

```
while(fgets(input, sizeof input, fp))
{
    long int val;
    char *tmp;

    val = strtol(line, &tmp, 0);

    if(*tmp == 0 || *tmp == '\n')
        printf("An integer was read: %ld\n", val);
    else
        printf("More than an integer was read: '%s'\n", line);
}
```

Comment: but I don't KNOW what input[x] is a digit, I just said that in the string some characters are integers, but I do not know where. I am trying to take a alphabet character and give it some integer value.

Comment: If you want to know if a character represents a digit, use `isdigit(input[x])`. This will return a non-zero value if `input[x]` is in the range [`'0'`, `'9'`]. With `val = val + input[x];` with a non-digit, you are summing the ASCII values of the characters. Whether you want that or not, I don't know, but it looks like that you want to convert a string like `"123"` to `123`. Then you would need to check only digit characters.

Answer (score 0):

If you are only converting the chars [1..0] to an integer value, all you have to do is

```
int main(void) {
    char input[14];

    scanf("%s", input);

    if (isdigit(input[0])) {
        int num = atoi(input);
        printf("%d\n", num);
    }
    else {
        printf("INPUT ERROR\n");
    }
}
```

Are you wanting to process alphabet characters as well and turn them into some integer value?

Comment: yes, turning alphabet characters into a integer value. Sorry I wasn't clear. Do you know how I can do that?

Comment: What formula do you want to use to turn alphabet chars into ints?  Use their ascii value?  If so use `int num = input[i]`.  Position in alphabet?  Use `int num = input[i] - 'A' + 1`

Answer (score 0):

Arrays in C are based on pointers, but that's not all they are. Arrays in C is just a bunch of those data types in a line in memory. That way you can just access the pointer of the lead variable, than hop down that list in order to get the next iteration of the array.

```
isdigit(*input[14])
```

This line will cause issues. Look at what `input` itself is. input is the pointer to your first element in that array. input is essentially saying `char* input = &array[0];` So lets say you dereference that input variable without that 14, you would get the first element. So we can say that `*input = array[0];` Do you see the issue here? You basically dereferenced it twice. If you had just done `insdigit(input[14])` that would work a bit better.

But onto the bigger issue here. You're taking a char array, that contains only chars, and you're trying to convert them into numbers. Remember that char and int are two different data types. Go ahead and check out this table: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/dd/ASCII-Table.svg

Recall that chars are basically just numbers that correspond to that ASCII value. For example your computer doesn't read a letter as a D, it reads it as 68 (or the binary format of 68). For numbers it's the same concept, even if it seems like it's just a number and you should be able to add it to `val`, you'd first have to subtract 48 or use the atoi function on digits.

So what can you do here? I can't say for sure without knowing exactly what you're trying to do as I don't know your specific needs, but just realize that you can already convert char into ints very easily. I believe you can just add a char to an int, although I may be mistaken (I do know there's a very easy way to add a char's value though, maybe you have to cast it first?) However recall that if you want the digits to count for face value, you'd have to subtract 48 from them first.

If you want to use atoi you can, however honestly I don't see the need here, since you're already converting regular chars to numbers here. It'd be sufficient to check to see if the char value is between 48 and 58 (or whatever the actual numbers are) and if they are then you could subtract that.

Hope this helped!